# Else-if in a complex function

Tags: c, if-statement, return

I've got this (example) code:

```
int c = getchar();
int other_variable = rand();

// set conditions based on user input, etc.

if (c == 'a') {
    // some code here
    return;
}

if (c == 'b') {
    // some code here
    if (other_variable == 0)
        return;
}

if (c == 'c') {
    // some code here
    return;
}

// rest of the conditions
```

I'd like to shorten this code by using `else if`s and removing the `return`s. I don't know how to do this, because the program should keep going through the if-statements only when `other_variable` isn't 2. What should I do?

Comment: Not very clear, and this should not be in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I'm making some leaps and assumptions. If the current function's ret type is void, shouldn't you be able to just put `if (!do_stuff())
        return;` at the top? If that's not what you're after then please provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It would be be great if you could elaborate the requirement. We cannot help you solely based on assumption from our end,

Comment: @VimalBhaskar  Done.

Comment: @Stargateur I clarified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can add the check in the condition and leave the body empty:

```
if (condition1) {
    do_something();
}    
else if (condition2 && !do_stuff()) {

} else if (...)
```

but this is confusing. You may find better ways to simplify than just removing returns, if you think more about your logic as a whole.